# Как проверить, что пользователь существует?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

У меня есть код:

```
function issetUser($usrnm, $psswrd, $pdo){
    try{
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?");
        $stmt->execute([$usrnm, $psswrd]); 
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        var_dump($user);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print "Error! : ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
```

Ета функция для логина которая проверяет существует ли такой юзер. Вопрос, как сделть так чтоб функция вернула положительный результат, если юзер существует, и отрицательный если нету?

Comment: Что у вас выводится после выполнения `var_dump($user);` в случае если есть такой пользователь и, если его нет? То есть, какие значения принимает `$user`?

Comment: Лучше выстройте логику правильно. У вас должна быть функция, которая получает пользователя по `username`. Другая функция должна проверять пароль у полученного юзера, используя php функцию `password_verify`

Comment: ты должен прописать код на подобие этого `if (!$то что нужно проверить) { echo ("Такого пользователя несуществует!"); }`

Comment: В вопросе жутакая каша. "выполнилась ли функция" и "существует ли юзер" -  это РАЗНЫЕ вопросы. Первое проверять вообще не надо. Запрос внутри проверяет не существует ли юзер, а существует ли такой юзер с таким паролем. Причем это делается неправильно. Что в итоге нужно получить? Верны ли введенные логин и пароль?

Comment: да правильно ли введены пароль и логин

Answer (score 0):

Здесь на самом деле два вопроса в одном.

В принципе, чтобы проверить существование пользователя с таким *логином*, функция уже делает то что надо, из неё надо просто убрать всё лишнее и добавить оператор `return`

```
function getUserByName($usrname, $pdo){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $stmt->execute([$usrname]); 
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Эта функция будет возвращать либо массив, если пользователь с таким именем существует, либо `false`.

В РНР нестрогая типизация и массив всегда можно использовать в условном операторе

```
$user = getUserByName($usrname, $pdo);
if ($user) {
    echo "exists";
} else {
    echo "not exists";
}
```

Теперь отвечу на второй вопрос, как узнать, правильно ли введены логин и пароль.

Но для этого надо сначала вспомнить что **пароли нельзя хранить в открытом виде**, а только в [хэшированном](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php). То есть при занесении пользователя в БД необходимо обарбатывать пароль функцией `password_hash()`

Поэтому для проверки пароля мы будем использовать функцию `password_verify()` а хэш пароля для сравнения получим из БД с помощью функции `getUserByName()`:

```
$user = getUserByName($usrname, $pdo);
if ($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
    echo "Логин и пароль введены правильно!";
}
```

Comment: Важное замечание, чтобы проверять `password_verify`, хэш должен быть создан `password_hash`

Comment: Ну так у меня и стоит ссылка на эту функцию

Comment: Многие используют в качестве хэша `md5` всё ещё

Comment: согласен никогда нельзя недооценивать читателя. добавил